# Sizing CPU and RAM for website

Tags: webserver, hosting, web-hosting

How do I count Ram and CPU  to my site? 
Accoriding to number of unique visitors per day and sustained visitors

Answer (score 0):

Memory and CPU are not visitors. To see how much memory your site uses, check how much memory it uses on the server's monitoring systems.

To see how much CPU it uses, check the server logs.